# Redis script load fails with error '=' expected near '<eof>'

Tags: redis, lua

I must be doing something horribly wrong, for a very simple lua script like this from a file test.lua

```lua
return redis.call("ping")
```

I am trying to load this from redis-cli :

```
script load test.lua
```

It tells me there is an error

> (error) ERR Error compiling script (new function): user_script:1: '=' expected near ''

While the same thing works, if I run eval command directly, it fails to do script load.  I suspected something to do with \r\n etc, but running dos2unix or unix2dos on the file yields no success.

Can someone help me with this..

Answer (score 1):

ok, my bad.  My understanding was wrong about script load.  It doesn't take from a file.  The script content has to be provided to the command, instead of a file name.  How stupid I was !